# Prevent exposing Laravel usage

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I use Wappalyzer add-on on chrome and recently it started finding out about the usage of Laravel framework on my projects.

how does it know about this and how can I hide this?

I think it may be because of one of the cookie's name that Laravel sets automatically, but have no idea how can I change it's name.

```
Cookie Name: laravel_session
```

**EDIT**: thanks to David's answer I could change cookie's name but it still tracks Laravel, so it shouldn't be the way Wappalyzer finds out about Laravel.

**EDIT2**: I've created a new controller and it didn't detect the framework! It seems that Wappalyzer caches the results for each URL!

Comment: Have a look at answer from @Akhtar Munir

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's probably the laravel cookie. It has a distinguishing feature in it's name 'laravel_session'. It would certainly explain where it gets the usage stats from. You can change the name of the cookie in `app/config/session.php`.

**Edit**

So Wappalyzer uses json to specify what it should be looking for. This is how it identifies Laravel:

```
"Laravel": {
    "website": "laravel.com",
    "cats": [ 18 ],
    "headers": { "Set-Cookie": "laravel_session" },
    "implies": "PHP"
}
```

It uses the headers property to identify what's going on. This would imply it does use the cookie name only...

For the complete list of app tracking rules, they're on the **[GitHub repo](https://github.com/AliasIO/Wappalyzer/blob/master/src/apps.json)**.

Comment: Session name changed, but it keeps tracking Laravel again!

Comment: Is it tracking it using the new cookie name?

Comment: I don't know how it tracks Laravel, but it isn't cookie's name, apparently.

Comment: Yes, I've created a new controller and it didn't detect the framework! It seems that it caches the results for each URL! Thanks

Comment: Ah good, I just added something that would confirm it is only the cookie to the answer.

Comment: Awesome, I was crawling it's github repository but didn't know what's going on... :D

Comment: If you want to see exactly how it detects any application take a look at https://github.com/ElbertF/Wappalyzer/blob/master/share/apps.json

Answer (score 6):

When requesting the laravel website for the first time with the laravel_session prefix while the detection plugin is running, Laravel website techs are detected and stored, so in the next time even if you've changed the prefix the laravel detected icon will still showup.

Best thing is to not ever activate the plugin while developing on the production server, and make sure to uncheck in plugin options the **"send data to the server"**.

Answer (score 5):

In the new laravel 5.2, you can change the cookie session name

By going to the **config folder** in the root of your laravel project and then **session.php**, scroll down till line **112** and
change this from   `'cookie' => 'laravel_session',` to w.e you want.

Comment: In Laravel 5.5 it's on the line ```125```.

Answer (score 5):

In laravel 5.7 and 5.8

If you want to hide it from Wapplyzer than you can change it in below way.

Change `APP_NAME=Laravel` to `APP_NAME=Any Name You want` in `.env` file.

Answer (score 2):

now it all went to https://github.com/AliasIO/wappalyzer/blob/master/src/technologies.json

so as  project `config/sessions.php` shows this for cookie:

```
'cookie' => env(
    'SESSION_COOKIE',
    Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel_session'), '_').'_session'
)
```

we have to proceed to its `env()` argumeent

(which is `laravel_session` as a default value in case the  `env()` fails).

THUS we have just to

get in `.env` file and change its APP_NAME 's value